# Printing out steps of movement on 4x4 grid in C++

Tags: c++

I'm working on this program in C++ where I have to print out a 4x4 grid and ask the user for starting (x,y) values and ending (x,y) values.

What I want the program to do is print out an `x` on the grid where the user wants it to start, and then prints out its path to the ending spot. I have the print function for the grid ready, now I just need to figure out how to get the grid to print each step.

The `x` can only move up, left, right, and down, so no diagonal movement. I also want the preceding `x` to remain on the next grid that gets printed out each step.

### Edit:

Here is my code that I have so far:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void print_grid(){

    cout << "  _______________ " << endl;
    cout << "1|___|___|___|___|" << endl;
    cout << "2|___|___|___|___|" << endl;
    cout << "3|___|___|___|___|" << endl;
    cout << "4|___|___|___|___|" << endl;
    cout << "   1   2   3   4  " << endl;
}

void find_path(int xStart, int yStart, int xEnd, int yEnd){
        print_grid();
}


int main(){
    int xStart, yStart, xEnd, yEnd;

    cout << "Welcome to the rover control panel." << endl;
    cout << "Your options for movement are on a 4x4 grid with x-values 1 through 4 and y-values 1 through 4." << endl;
    cout << "Where would you like to start the rover out?" << endl;
    cout << "Enter your starting x coordinate: " << endl;
    cin >> xStart;
    cout << "Enter your starting y coordinate: " << endl;
    cin >> yStart;
    cout << "Enter your ending x coordinate: " << endl;
    cin >> xEnd;
    cout << "Enter your ending y coordinate: " << endl;
    cin >> yEnd;

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sounds like an interesting problem. What have you done so far? Please show us code.

Comment: So you don't know how to find a path between the start and the end, or you don't know how to display it?

Comment: I posted the code in the main post. And I'm trying to decide how to go about finding the path between the start and the end, and then based on that, I need to figure out how to display it step by step to the user.

I think I'm going to use arrays to find the path, but I'm also looking into other options. I'm imagining that a for loop is going to be involved in printing out the grid in each step.

Comment: @Benzel think of y as north-south and x as east-west. If your start is south of where your finish is, you need to move north. If it's east of your finish you need to move west. Just keep on making the y start point move up or down till it's even with the finish point, then do the same with the x.

Answer (score 0):

I would make something like this:

```
void print_grid(std::vector<int> cells_in_path){

    cout << "  _______________ " << endl;
    int i_cell = 0; char c;
    for (int row = 1; row <= 4; row++){
        cout << row;
        for (int col = 1; col <= 4; col++, i_cell++){

            // checking if current cell presents in path
            if (std::find(vector.begin(), vector.end(), item) != vector.end())
                c = 'x';
            else
                c = '_';
            cout << "|_" << c << "_";
        }
        cout << "|" << endl;
    cout << "   1   2   3   4  " << endl;

    return;
}
```

Here `std::vector<int> cells_in_path` is vector of indexes of cells included in path (indexes from 0 to 15). Then you should fill `cells_in_path` inside `find_path(...)` - step by step or whole at once, decide it yourself.

And if it's C++ so I would make these functions as methods in one class.

Answer (score 0):

```
int start_x, start_y, finish_x, finish_y = 0;

start_x = 0;
start_y = 3;

finish_x = 3;
finish_y = 1;

cout << "+------------+\n";

for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    cout << "|";

    for(int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
    {
        // start point
        if(j == start_x && i == start_y)
        {
            cout << " S ";
        }
        // finish point
        else if(j == finish_x && i == finish_y)
        { 
            cout << " F ";
        }
        else
        {
            cout << " _ ";
        }
    }

    cout << "|";

    cout << endl;
}
cout << "+------------+\n";
```

OUTPUT:

```
+------------+
| _  _  _  _ |
| _  _  _  F |
| _  _  _  _ |
| S  _  _  _ |
+------------+
```

that's for the display. You're better off creating a 2d array with all ' _ 's and then changing the position of the start and finish. As for the path, your gonna want to check if the start's x and y are greater than or less than the finish's x and y and move accordingly. You can do it with while loops or recursion if you wanna be fancy.